# API Return JSON in Browser but not Works in Postman or using jQuery

Tags: javascript, api, cors, postman, blockchain

I'm trying to fetch data from Blockchain API [Here](https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/mx96dAzepcd86VTyo4VshSmizyxAR7sJ6P), it works only when i access the link using Chrome, but 
when i using jQuery .getJSON() i got this error message :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/mx96dAzepcd86VTyo4VshSmizyxAR7sJ6P' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I know this is because CORS, so i tried using CORS Plugin to solve it,but i am getting another error :

> GET https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/mx96dAzepcd86VTyo4VshSmizyxAR7sJ6P 503

after that i tried using postmant and i got meessage :

> Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.

Here is my code

```
url = 'https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/mx96dAzepcd86VTyo4VshSmizyxAR7sJ6P'
$.getJSON(url,function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
```

Comment: You have to Implement/Apply Cors Policy on your backend(Serverside/Api) . Otherwise you wont be able to make a get request using ajax.

Comment: The page that is returned by that end point is a CloudFlare DDOS protection page. Are you sure that is the correct URL?

Comment: I dont have access to serverside/api @MuhammadAftab

Comment: yes, [here](https://my.dogechain.info/api) API documentation @Turnip

Answer (score 0):

This URL is protected by cloudflare, so loading this URL through postman, Cloudflare detects Postman to not be a real browser, making it pass through a mid-page. The result you get from this call using Postman, is the cloudflare protection page.